# SqlDataSource erroring when retrieving NVARCHAR(max) column

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

I'm writing a small ASP .Net application in order to retrieve data from a SQL database.  The application uses drop downs in order to select what the next drop down should contain and when a page is selected, it should retrieve the HTML from the database.  Everything is working until it gets to the retrival of the HTML data.  When I try to retrieve the data, I get:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
>   An unknown error occurred while
>   processing the request on the server.
>   The status code returned from the
>   server was: 500

The HTML column is a defined as `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, but I can't see this causing a problem.  The application works if I set the `DataValueField` to another column.  Has one else come across a problem like this?  Maybe someone could shine some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Just needed to set `ValidateRequest` to `false` at the `Page` level.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I noted when dealing with varchar(max) columns is that the framework still commonly expects to have a size associated with it.  What I ended up having to do was specify the length as -1 to get it to accept a varchar(max) field.  Your error message doesn't indicate that this is the problem, but you might try experimenting with it rather than turning off the validation, which could possibly have other repercussions.